# Visual Studio - No items available for C#

Tags: visual-studio

When I want to add items to my ASP.NET Web Application in Visual Studio 2022 it always shows that there are no items available under Visual C#
Why is this the case and how may I fix it?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE7xN.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln34Y.jpg)

I did check that .NET project and item templates is checked

Answer (score 0):

Open visual studio installer -> modify -> check on ASP.Net enviroment for web development -> install it.

If this one is not working try to install individual components.